# How to protect static resources in a Blazor webapp?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor webapp SSR+Server secured with the new Identity Authentication offered from the template of blazor 8 webapp.

The problem is how to secure the static files that are living under the wwwroot folder. Not the whole wwwroot folder must be secured, because else the resources used by the html (eg. css, js, png, etc) for the login page and other (reset password, email confirmation, etc.) would not work. Indeed [this kind of solution](https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/how-can-i-protect-static-files-with-authorization-on-asp-net-core-4l0o) is not viable.

eg. I want to protect docs and images but not assets (and subfolders)

```
wwwroot
|-- assets
    |-- css
    |-- siteimages
    |-- js
|-- docs
    |-- subfolders
|-- images
    |-- subfolders
```

I know I could move outside and treat them server side (eg. docs and images could live in a App_Data outside wwwroot), but for example if I have a html mini-editor that offer the upload image feature I have to store under wwwroot in order to  have relative url like “/images/foo.jpg” to display correctly in the editor and where used.

In the old days of webforms I remember you could add in the web.config a <location path=".."> that you could protect or allow with a allow/deny authorization...

Is there something similar here?

Answer (score 0):

You could try add following middlware before `app.UseStaticFiles()` to prevent certain path from being visit.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var path = context.Request.Path;
    if (path.StartsWithSegments("/docs") || path.StartsWithSegments("/images"))
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("path not allowed");
    }
    else
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
});
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: That's a god point... but it is disallowed even if I'm logged. So I guess I have to find out, how to check authentication state inside program.cs